# What are the trade-offs between monolithic and micro Lambda functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We keep running into the question of how to organize responsibilities into AWS Lambda functions. An example of such involves CRUD operations:

Lets say we have four classes, W, X, Y, and Z, each with a set of CRUD operations. If we have a lambda for each operation and each class, those Lambdas will be very simple, maybe too simple to justify a lambda. We could write a single lambda for all of a class' CRUD operations (create W, read W, update W, delete W). It would have a switch statement to choose the right CRUD operation. We could also write a single lambda for each CRUD operation for all classes (create W, create X, create Y, create Z). We could even have a single lambda do it all, with nested switch statements around the business logic.

My experience programming on single computers makes me loathe the idea of having lambdas do anything other than one CRUD operation for one class. I've also watched several presenters state that my loathing is well placed. Unfortunately, they didn't provide any explanation, so I can't choose what's appropriate for my context.

Without straining much, I can think of two reasons in support of monolithic lambdas:

1. Lambda cold starts would be amortized across more functionality, and would be incurred less often.
2. The programming overhead to a lambda is larger than a function. Each lambda requires management (deployment, choosing appropriate resource parameters, etc.).

Other than the complexity brought by pulling a parameter and passing it to a switch statement, I'm coming up empty on arguments for micro lambdas.

Has your experience yielded any other insight into the trade-offs between monolithic and micro lambdas?

Comment: Some advice from Martin Fowler: [Go Macro First, then Micro](https://martinfowler.com/articles/break-monolith-into-microservices.html#GoMacroFirstThenMicro)

Comment: That article on Martin Fowler, has some interesting strategies for breaking a monolithic service into microservices, and knowing when to stop. It helped, but wasn't quite the silver bullet I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Micro Lambdas”, as you call it, will actually probably incur more cold start cost as you’re most likely using the same SDK to carry out all 4 CRUD operations - your dependencies are most likely going to be the same & now, instead of 1 cold start for 4 CRUD operations, you have 4 cold starts.

Only split a Lambda down if you need to have some conscious split in business logic or the running duration  of the Lambda keep dangerously increasing.

Otherwise, for CRUD operations, keep them together 100% of the time; you’d just be creating more hassle for yourself creating 4 different Lambdas, incurring 4 cold starts, for CRUD operations on *one* resource.

A great personal indicator I use for determining if a Lambda is getting too big is taking a look at the execution role - do the policies in this role make sense to be *together*?

If not, split otherwise keep together for the benefits of an easier to manage project.

Creating a new Lambda for every new CRUD operation is taking the single responsibility principle down to a level where it shouldn’t be.

Comment: IMHO, your advice is sound in most circumstances, but I wanted to know more about the trade-offs between monolothic and micro Lambda functions so that I could choose the right approach in any circumstance. The best article I've found is [here](https://www.serverless.com/blog/serverless-architecture-code-patterns/), and gives four patterns along with a concise explanation of their benefits and drawbacks. In our case, a services, rather than microservices approach is appropriate, which is exactly as you suggest.

Comment: @Mark I can only write up so much haha! in your specific case yes, but for most cases the stuff above applies pretty well (as you know) - glad you sorted it out in the end :)

Comment: AWS has the Lambda monolith listed as an anti pattern. However, I agree that this should be the default starting place until an application grows to a size where it either logically makes sense to break apart or cold start times are prohibitive. But making one lambda for every get request is tedious even with CDK to help you out.